# convert json String to datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

While converting json string datatable facing an issue with , (comma) value in value field.

actualy my json string is `[{"BNo":"345","GNo":"3453","FirstName":"fjai","LastName":"ljai","Address":"BARETI,CEVO, 13/2","Telephone":"051682247","BirthDate":"23-Jan-1981","Email":""}]`

In that please look at the address scenario `"Address":"BARETI,CEVO, 13/2"`

It has the , in the values field. While converting the string to data base i got error. Here the code which i used convert json string to datatable

```
public DataTable JsonStringToDataTbl(string jsonString)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
    List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();
    foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
    {
        string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
        foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
        {
            try
            {
                int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");
                string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
                {
                    ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
    }
    foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
    {
        string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
        DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (string rowData in RowData)
        {
            try
            {
                int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(nr);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

The code must omit the , in the value field.. what can i do

Comment: Why not convert json into objects, then edit the property in the object and after that transform it into a datarow?

Comment: If u dont mind can say how can i do it.. Actually a wcf web service returns the json string as a output... now i want to change as a table

Comment: if i were you i would take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json it will save you alot of time. It makes you easely convert your json to objects and back :)

Comment: Or please tel me how can pass datatable from wcf resfull service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your keys are unknown at the time of being read, then you can use the [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and the [JProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) classes from JSON.Net to retrieve the keys and their values like this:

```
private void printKeysAndValues(string json)
{
    var jobject = (JObject)((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json))[0];
    foreach (var jproperty in jobject.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", jproperty.Name, jproperty.Value);
    }
}
```

Applied to two different JSON input string, retrieves the key/value pair:

```
var json1 = @"[{""BNo"":""345"",""GNo"":""3453"",""FirstName"":""fjai"",""LastName"":""ljai"",""Address"":""BARETI,CEVO, 13/2"",""Telephone"":""051682247"",""BirthDate"":""23-Jan-1981"",""Email"":""""}]";
var json2 = @"[{""Test"": ""A"", ""Text"":""some text"", ""Numbers"":""123""}]";
printKeysAndValues(json1);
Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
printKeysAndValues(json2);
```

And the output is:

```
BNo - 345
GNo - 3453
FirstName - fjai
LastName - ljai
Address - BARETI,CEVO, 13/2
Telephone - 051682247
BirthDate - 23-Jan-1981
Email - 
-------------------
Test - A
Text - some text
Numbers - 123
```

---

One possibility would be to use the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd264741.aspx) keyword. You can directly access the field like this:

```
var json = @"[{""BNo"":""345"",""GNo"":""3453"",""FirstName"":""fjai"",""LastName"":""ljai"",""Address"":""BARETI,CEVO, 13/2"",""Telephone"":""051682247"",""BirthDate"":""23-Jan-1981"",""Email"":""""}]";
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
// take the first element of the array
string address = data[0].Address;
Console.WriteLine(address.Replace(",", " "));
```

The output is:

```
BARETI CEVO  13/2
```

Note that `String.Replace` does not fail, if the symbol that should be replaced is not currently present, so `"test".Replace(",", " ");` will return `test`.

Another possibility is to use the in ASP.NET build in JSON converter (serializer/deserializer) - [NewtonSoft JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You can use it in order to regain the structured data. You need to create a class that represents the JSON structure:

```
public class Data
{
    public string BNo { get; set; }
    public string GNo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Telephones { get; set; }
    public string BirthDates { get; set; }
    public string Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Then the current JSON can be converted to an object of type `Data` using the [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) method:

```
var json = @"[{""BNo"":""345"",""GNo"":""3453"",""FirstName"":""fjai"",""LastName"":""ljai"",""Address"":""BARETI,CEVO, 13/2"",""Telephone"":""051682247"",""BirthDate"":""23-Jan-1981"",""Email"":""""}]";
// remove square braces [ and ] at the start resp. end
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json.Substring(1).Substring(0, json.Length - 2));
```

Now you can access the `Address` field and for example replace the `,` symbol:

```
Console.WriteLine(data.Address.Replace(",", " "));
```

The output is:

```
BARETI CEVO  13/2
```

I think your service returns also the wrong JSON format. JSON always starts with an object (when not in JavaScript), meaning that everything at the top level must be enclosed within curly braces `{` and `}`. If the service should return an array, then it should look like this `{"results": [{"BNo":"...},{...}]}`. If you can't change the service, then you can adapt / correct the returned string. Add a typed model for the array:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public Data[] data { get; set; }
}
```

and then create a correct JSON object holding an array:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataHolder>("{\"data\":" + json + "}");
Console.WriteLine(data.data[0].Address.Replace(",", " "));
```

The output is again the same.

Comment: Thanks @pasty but the column is dynamic.what i can do

Comment: Which column is dynamic? Do you mean that you don't have always the name `Address`, instead the columns are named differently every time? If the column `Address` has a different content every time, then the `Replace` will work, even if no `,` symbol is present!

Comment: If all columns are dynamic, then a `Key/Value` structure would be probably more suited. The fetching of the *name*  and the *value* will be a lot easier.

Comment: All the columns are dynamic, which is not same in all the time.

Comment: I have updated my answer - I added a function that retrieves the keys and the values from a JSON string. As long the structure of the JSON string is always the same, the retrieval will always work.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JSON value to C# objects using `Newtonsoft`. This would be easy for you. Once you have converted to the below object, you can easily modify the `Address` property to remove the `','` value.

```
public class RootObject
{
  public string BNo { get; set; }
  public string GNo { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Telephone { get; set; }
  public string BirthDate { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Use the below line to convert to C# object

```
var jsonString = "The output of your webservice";
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Now `obj` instance holds the C# object which is very easy to manipulate.

Comment: The columns will be geenerated gynamic. it will be known at the time of the execution

Comment: What all columns are dynamic?